# Risk Aversion under Worst Case Utility Representation

Tags: microeconomics, decision-theory, uncertainty

The preference relations (≿A and ≿B) over lotteries is defined as:
**p ≿ q iff min{v(z) : p(z) > 0} ≥ min{v(z) : q(z) > 0}**

Under what conditions can you say that ≿A is more risk averse than ≿B?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi. I have edited the question. I am given a preference relation and have to find relative risk aversion. I know how to do that in the case when preferences are defined by Expected Utility but don't know how to do it in this case

Comment: What is $p(z)$? What is $v(z)$? What is $q(z)$? Clarifying these definitions would get you a better answer, its too undefined at the moment.